# How to add fields to a map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a map like this:

```
{:a 1 :b 20}
```

: and I want to make sure that certain fields are not missing from the map:

```
(:a :b :c :d )
```

: Is there a function to merge the two, something like :

```
(merge-missing-keys {:a 1 :b 20} (:a :b :c :d ))
```

: which can produce :

```
{:a 1 :b 20 :c nil :d nil}
```

?

### Update:

With some pointers from the answers I found that this can be done like this:

```
(defn merge-missing-keys [
                           a-set 
                           some-keys
                         ]
          (merge-with 
                         #(or %1 %2) 
                         a-set  
                         (into {} (map (fn[x] {x nil}) some-keys))))

(merge-missing-keys {:a 1 :b 20} '(:a :b :c :d :e ))
```

Comment: (into {} (map #(vector % (map %)) keys))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `merge-with`:

> Returns a map that consists of the rest of the maps conj-ed onto
>   the first. If a key occurs in more than one map, the mapping(s)
>   from the latter (left-to-right) will be combined with the mapping in
>   the result by calling (f val-in-result val-in-latter).

So the following will merge all maps with one actual value selected from the maps or `nil`.

```
(merge-with #(or %1 %2) 
            {:a 1 :b 2} 
            {:a nil :b nil :c nil :d nil})
; -> {:d nil :c nil :b 2 :a 1}
```

This will probably be enough for you to build your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can always just merge into your default array as follows:

```
(merge
  {:a nil :b nil :c nil :d nil} ; defaults
  {:a 1 :b 20})                 ; current values

=> {:a 1, :b 20, :c nil, :d nil}
```

Comment: Easier to grok than the others

Answer (score 3):

A riff on @mikera's answer, to make it work when you don't have the keys available as literals:

```
(let [keys [:a :b :c :d]]
 (merge (zipmap keys (repeat nil))
        {:a 1 :b 20}))
```